# retrieving class variables after inheritance

Tags: python, class

So i'm making a hangman game in tkinter and I'm trying to make the buttons disappear when pressed and reappear when the restart button is pressed. I'm still learning to code and have tried to adjust it to include classes to make the code clearer. This is the code I've used to create the button widgets:

```
class Buttons:

    def __init__(self, letter, column, row):
        self.letter = letter
        self.column = column
        self.row = row

    def create(self):
        column = self.column
        row = self.row
        letter = self.letter
        self = tk.Button(window, text=self.letter, bg = colour, font=FONT,
                         command=lambda : check(letter))
        self.place(relx=column, rely=row)
```

And then I place the buttons like this and it all works fine:

```
A = Buttons('A', column1, row1).create()
```

What I want to do however is access the 'self.letter', 'self.row', and 'self.column' outside of the class definition, however it says that the object is a Nonetype when I try to use 'A.letter' and it has no attribute letter. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\cameron\Documents\Python\Hangman\Hangman v2.1.py", line       227, in <module>
    print(A.letter)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'letter'
```

Does anyone know how I could access this?

Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't use inheritance. Please post the complete traceback and the code where the error is raised (with some context).

Comment: `A` is None (so it is not a "Buttons" and has no attribute "letter"). Show the code where you assign `A`.

Comment: I have included the code where A was assigned, it is: A = Buttons('A', column1, row1).create()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reassign `self`.  Try this:

```
    def create(self):
        #column = self.column   # don't need these
        #row = self.row
        #letter = self.letter
        self.tkbutton = tk.Button(window, text=self.letter, bg = colour, font=FONT, command=lambda : check(letter))
            # Stashes the tk.Button instance away in `self.tkbutton`.
        self.tkbutton.place(relx=self.column, rely=self.row)
```

`self` stays the same all the time, so you should never say `self = <whatever>`.  Instead, use `self.<some field name> = <whatever value>`.  Then the `<some field name>` will be accessible from outside as `A.<some field name>`.

Then, to use the button, try

```
A = Buttons('A', column1, row1)    # calls A.__init__()
A.create()
# at this point A.tkbutton exists and is accessible.
```

Although a better approach might be to combine `create`'s work into `__init__` so that the button is created and placed in the `A=Buttons(...)` call.

**Edit** The reason you got a `NoneType` error is that `create()` does not include a `return` statement.  Therefore, its return value is `None`.  As a result, `A=Buttons(...).create()` returns `None`, i.e., a `NoneType`.

Comment: Wouldn't the contents of create() be better off inside __init__(), then instantiating a button would be A = Buttons(...). Not being clever, I just want to understand.

Comment: @Steve, possibly, depending on the use case.  Actually added that to the answer while you were typing your comment :) .

Comment: Excellent news, I'm not as dumb as I thought I was.

Comment: I've learned that people hear that constructors shouldn't do too much, so they make constructors not actually construct the object. The constructor (or in Python's case, initializer) should do whatever is *actually* needed to create your class and make it stable.

Comment: Cheers this is really helping, although the reason I created a separate create function was to try and simplify the removal and then resetting of the widgets when the game is reset.